# Arduino board to control microwave oven?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, electronics

So I've taken apart an old microwave oven with a touch-sensitive LCD screen. I understand that I could die from playing around with this, so I've disconnected the high-voltage transformer and the magnetron. I'm also not going to remove any of the safety switches like the door switch. My question is, how is the microwave controlled? I'm thinking there is a computer chip somewhere in the circuit, and I'm looking to replace it with an Arduino board plus some extras, like AC relays and such. I'm curious as to how the microwave oven controls its functions, like power level, cooking time, and the beeping. Any advise as to how I could get started interfacing?

Is the power level controlled by PWM by any chance? Can you PWM alternating current?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much all proprietary. It can be done, but you'd have to replace all the circuitry with the Arduino, interfacing with the existing magnetic and mechanical devices and doing everything in your own code.

Power level is controlled by PWM, but it's *extremely* low frequency PWM, on the order of 0.05Hz (20s period). That's why there are two different sounds that come from the microwave when it's not at full power; one when the magnetron is active, and one when it is off.

Answer (score 2):

There is no power level in a microwave. It's just on or off. They lower the power by turning on the magnetron for a few seconds, and then off for a few second. You can actually hear this.

It's probably turned on by a relay, triac, or solid state relay. The magnetron is just requires a high voltage to work; nothing else.

The programmes, timing, and handling of the buttons is done by some microcontroller, similar to an arduino.

Comment: So the magnetron is just set at it's own "power level?" There's no variation of the output, it's just how long it is turned on? And I'm guessing if I set the power level on the LCD to full power, the magnetron would be on 100% of the time?

Comment: @user3211857: Correct.

Comment: Hmm, so if I wanted to control the operation with an Arduino, could I hook the Arduino up to an AC relay module, hook that up to the switch that turns on the magnetron, and program the Arduino when to digitalWrite(pin, HIGH)? Any ideas?

Comment: You wouldn't use a relay for pwm. Most relays can't switch fast enough .

Comment: You wouldn't use a relay for *subsecond* PWM. A microwave doesn't use subsecond PWM for its magnetron.

Comment: Just keep the door switches in series with the power going into the transformer. That way, the magnetron is disabled when the door is opened. Also use a relay that is rated for the amount of amps going through it. Note that there is also a motor, and probably a fan in parallel to this transformer, so the plate is spinning, and the fan is cooling the magnetron. Also keep the snubber circuit on the incoming AC line. Other than that, you got the basic idea of how to operate it correct.

Comment: Just hopping in here to point out that lots of newer microwaves do have multiple power levels for the magnetron. For older microwaves and some newer ones, the "on or off only" is still true, though. If the microwave in question is one of the new multiple power ones, there is no problem programming it as just on or off like an old fashioned one. And it's a lot safer than measuring and controlling the variable power settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn more about AC power circuits start with relays (start with 5v or 12v dc as a lot safer , cheaper and easier) something like the spark fun power tail if you really do want to control 120V devices note its only on/off control, not different power levels. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10747

You can generate AC from DC by using pwm at a lower voltage and driving a transformer
or a digital inverter. Can use an arduino to do it if you wanted to.
Use pwm function, then via optocouplers (to protect the arduino) to power mosfets or an h-bridge to drive a transformer. Can fairly easily produce 120V/240V output

Time to grab a good basic electronics book like Art of Electronics (should be able to find a pdf version) 
3rd edition is finally getting published in 2015

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've already messed around with AC voltage (luckily I'm still alive). I just used a relay module and hooked it up to my Arduino and the Wall outlet to control Christmas lights. But I haven't tried what you describe, generate AC to DC. Sounds pretty interesting.

Comment: other way around generate AC from DC. Thats how the static inverters for cars ,boats and aircraft can generate 120V/240V AC from 12 or 24V dc. First step is to get the arduino to output a sine wave (or close to a sine wave ). Learn more about pwm (also good for led brightness control)